# Tabela em Postgre campo ID não é com auto incremento

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, administração-postgresql, quasar

vou explicar meu problema:

No meu SQL no sistema já veio o erro no INSERT, informando que o campo id, que é autoincremento está informando que é null:

```
INSERT INTO cliente_sub_grupo (id,id_cliente,subgrupo,tipo_atendimento,ind_valor_titular_igual_contrato,ind_valor_dependente_igual_contrato,valor_titular,valor_dependente)  VALUES (:id,:id_cliente,:subgrupo,:tipo_atendimento,:ind_valor_titular_igual_contrato,:ind_valor_dependente_igual_contrato,:valor_titular,:valor_dependente)
```

```
INSERT INTO cliente_sub_grupo (id,id_cliente,subgrupo,tipo_atendimento,ind_valor_titular_igual_contrato,ind_valor_dependente_igual_contrato,valor_titular,valor_dependente)  VALUES (:id,:id_cliente,:subgrupo,:tipo_atendimento,:ind_valor_titular_igual_contrato,:ind_valor_dependente_igual_contrato,:valor_titular,:valor_dependente)
```

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>         Detalhe: Failing row contains (null, 12, vcxvxc, F, t, t, 1, 1, ativo).

Depois de olhar o código resolvi olhar diretamente no BD e na imagem a seguir eu faço um cadastro teste, deixando o campo ID como em branco e dá o erro da segunda imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o erro quando insiro diretamente do BD (o mesmo erro no console de minha aplicação no INSERT):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo erro de console:

> cliente-sub-grupo.insert org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>   Detalhe: Failing row contains (null, 12, vcxvxc, F, t, t, 1, 1, ativo).
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>         Detalhe: Failing row contains (null, 12, vcxvxc, F, t, t, 1, 1, ativo).

O que pode ser e como consertar este erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, se o campo id é autoincrement então não precisa declará-los no seu insert.
Por exemplo, imagina que você tem uma tabela frutas:

```
CREATE TABLE frutas(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   nome VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

E o insert ficaria assim:

```
INSERT INTO frutas(nome) VALUES('laranja');
```

Repare que não informei o campo id no insert.
No seu caso teria que ser assim:

```
INSERT INTO cliente_sub_grupo (id_cliente,subgrupo,tipo_atendimento,ind_valor_titular_igual_contrato,ind_valor_dependente_igual_contrato,valor_titular,valor_dependente)  VALUES (:id_cliente,:subgrupo,:tipo_atendimento,:ind_valor_titular_igual_contrato,:ind_valor_dependente_igual_contrato,:valor_titular,:valor_dependente)
```

Comment: Não estava no INSERT o erro. Este Insert que postei era do console de uma gambiara de uma outra empresa que passou este job de uma biblioteca chamada Trust. Fazendo o teste direto no banco de dados (INSERT) mesmo deixando o campo id em branco, dava o mesmo erro. Era erro na tabela, que foi corrigido como mencionei a cima.

Answer (score 0):

@Murilo Portugal

Já resolvi, fiz tudo isso que sugeriu e outros testes aqui, mas o erro é que no campo `id` na coluna `Default`, como na imagem a seguir, faltou o:

```
nextval('pessoa_id_pessoa_seq'::regclass)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E funcionou.

Comment: Se você declarar o campo como SERIAL então isto estará implícito. Veja a explicação do tipo de dado SERIAL em: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: @Ramos, exatamente como o amigo acima disse, para utilizar autoincrement utilize o SERIAL no postgre, desse modo fica implícito, na minha resposta considerei que você já estivesse utilizando ele, que é o mais comum. Mas de qualquer forma que bom que deu certo